# Generating 0-255 3 times... double or triple loop?

Tags: javascript, arrays

Im sure this is another time I'm over complicating things, or just making myself loopy.

With just vanilla javascript, i want to make this code output an array of every rgb color code, (im using 25 instead of 255 just for sanity)

```
var a = [];
    for( var i = 0; i < 25; i++ ) {
for( var j = 0; j < 4; j++ ) {
     a.push(i)
      console.log('rgb('+a+')');
    }
}
```

the above outputs this 25 times:
rgb(0,0,0,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4,5,5,5,6.... so on ...25,25,25)

Then i tried this, or something like this, i lost what i had planned to show as example i think lol.

```
var a = [];
for( var j = 0; j < 4; j++ ) {
    for( var i = 0; i < 25; i++ ) {
     a.push(i)
      console.log('rgb('+a+')');
    }
    for( var k = 0; k < 4; k++ ) {
      console.log('rgb('+a+')');
    }
}
```

either way.
everything i've tried doesn't do what i want. i've tried to create a function too, still kinda lost in it.

ok, so this is another version i created, almost does it again, but not quite right:

```
var n = [];
for( var i = 0; i < 25; i++ ) {
    n.push(i);
}

var a = [];
n.forEach( function() { 
    for(j = 0; j<3;j++) { 
        var b = j
    }
    return a.push(n); 
});
console.log(a);
```

outputs 25 arrays with arrays 0-25;

i know it's something to do with arrays of arrays. thats the where i fail always, foreach loops and arrays have always been my downfall.

Comment: What's your final goal? Obviously you're now taking a wrong turn so please let us show you something better that will achieve same result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use three loops:

```
// READ THE BELOW BEFORE YOU RUN THIS
var r, g, b, rarray, garray, barray;
rarray = [];
for (r = 0; r < 256; ++r) {
    garray = [];
    rarray.push(garray);
    for (g = 0; g < 256; ++g) {
        barray = [];
        garray.push(barray);
        for (b = 0; b < 256; ++b) {
          barray.push({r: r, g: g, b: b});
        }
    }
}
```

That produces an array (`rarray`) of arrays (each `garray`), each of which in turn contains an array (each `barray`) of objects. Each object has an `r`, `g`, and `b` value.

Note that [as selbie points out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6007377/generating-0-255-3-times-double-or-triple-loop/6007518#6007518), you'll end up with a total of `256 * 256 * 256 = 16,777,216` entries spread across the various arrays. You'll have `256 * 256 = 65,536` `barray`s and `256` `garray`s. In all, that's `1 + 256 + (256 * 256) + (256 * 256 * 256) = 16,843,009` objects. Since all of these objects ([including the arrays](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2011/01/myth-of-arrays.html)) are actually key=value maps, each entry will have a key portion and a value portion, and so just the references to those will be four bytes each. Then there's the actual key data for the array entries (1-3 characters = 2-6 bytes *minimum*) and the key data for each of our 16M final objects (which have three keys each, `r`, `b`, and `g`). Plus some other overhead. The details will vary a *lot* by JavaScript environment, but we're probably talking *no less than* (waves hands) 32-64 bytes per entry, for a total in memory of ~538MB-1076MB. Now, that's not a lot by modern computer standards, but it's a lot for a web page. :-) I used Chrome to do it, and it took ~1GB (did it in about 4 seconds — gotta love Chrome). In contrast, after several minutes and >2GB of RAM use, I gave up on Firefox. I wouldn't go near this in IE with a barge-pole.

[Live example](http://jsbin.com/imoyo4/2) (using only `0..4` rather than `0..255`).

Comment: Yeah I'm aware of the 16,000 number of color combos, i didn't want to print them all out, just save in an array. I was just doing console.log to see what i was getting, hence the smaller number range (25).

Comment: i knew it had to be a triple loop. is there anyway to do it in less than that though?
and i mean without using a helper function or other thing like that.
i mean, for example i was trying stuff like:
[].forEach(num.push()) or something along that lines of psuedo.
It's just so much simpler to create the same thing.

Comment: @jaredwill: 16 *million*, not 16 thousand. Even just putting them in an array will be very, very expensive and won't work on many browsers out there. And why do it? Just looking something up in the array involves just as much calculation as actually creating the thing. No, there's no "shorter" way to do it (I don't think the loops are long, frankly). There is a way to use `forEach` to do it (on browsers that support `forEach`, it's quite new), but it doesn't buy you anything in terms of brevity (in this case) and adds the over head of function calls.

Comment: Right, I meant million, Anyways, thanks for helping me with this, it's not a feasible thing to do I realize. It was easier to do this with hsl I found, only I kept the l part set to 50% so I wasn't getting every single color possible I guess. It only required 2 for loops, and is significantly faster too.

Answer (score 1):

If you want EVERY color, then then question may be moot.  This is because if you want EVERY color (range 0-255 for R, G, and B), then that is 256*256*256 possible combinations.  **That's 16 million colors!**  Do you really want to print them all out or put them all in an array?

Or did you really mean to say, "all grey scale colors from rgb(0,0,0) to rgb(255,255,255) " ?

In any case, here's some code that will print out every color in increments of 16 instead of 1.  This will print out a more manageable 4K colors.  If you really, really, wanted EVERY color, change "var step" inside the DumpColors function from 16 to 1.  But you've been warned.

```
function color(r, g, b) {
    this.red = r;
    this.green = g;
    this.blue = b;
}


function DumpColors() {

    var r, g, b;    
    var col;
    var a = [];
    var step = 16;

    for (b = 0; b <= 255; b += step) {

        for (g = 0; g <= 255; g += step) {

            for (r = 0; r <=255; r += step) {

                col = new color(r,g,b);
                a.push(col);

                try {
                    console.log("rgb(" + r + "," + g + "," + b + ")" );
                }
                catch(err) {
                     ;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return a;
}
```

Comment: +1, but using a constructor seems pretty inefficient, why not just `a.push({r:r, g:g, b:b});`?